# Dual Monitors at 2560x1440 on Nvidia GTX 960

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have a PC running Ubuntu 14.04 with an NVIDIA GTX 760 / 2GB GDDR5 graphics card, which has two DVI ports, and I've been running a single 2560x1440 resolution monitor on this with no problems.

I've just got a second monitor with the same resolution, and it's having difficulty driving both at full resolution. I can get things running at 1920x1080 on the 2nd monitor with no problem, but if I try to set the second monitor at a higher resolution, it either fails to display anything, or produces a garbled display.

It displays at full resolution on the new monitor fine, when that's the only monitor.

Does anyone know if it's possible to drive two 2560x1440 displays with a 960 on Ubuntu? Some googling suggests yes, but that's probably on Windows. Will anything change when 16.04 comes out, or do I need to upgrade my graphics card?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: What version of the NVidia drivers do you have?

Comment: Should be the latest binary driver for 14.04 64bit: 340.96 according to nvidia-settings